# SQL SELECT and join multiple tables erron in query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, dropdown

I have this query working as expected:

```
        $sql = '
SELECT s.rowid
     , f.fk_soc
     , s.nom
     , f.datef
     , sc.fk_soc
     , sc.fk_user
     , u.rowid
     , u.firstname
     , u.lastname
  FROM societe s
  JOIN societe_commerciaux sc 
    ON s.rowid = sc.fk_soc
  JOIN user u 
    ON sc.fk_user = u.rowid
  LEFT 
  JOIN facture f 
    ON s.rowid = f.fk_soc
 GROUP 
    BY s.rowid
HAVING MAX(f.datef) <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '.$db->escape($dlo).' DAY
';
        $resql = $db->query($sql);
        if (!$resql) {
            dol_print_error($db);
        }
```

Background:

user - table with the user's first name and last name with primary identif. `rowid`

Societe - table with client names `s.nom` primary identif. `rowid`

facture - table with client's invoices with date `datef` and `fk_soc` which is the client id (s.rowid)

societe_commerciaux - makes the connection which user is representative for each client by matching `fk_soc` (which is actually s.rowid) with fk_user (which is u.rowid)

The working script lists all clients that don't have an invoice for a period set with the `$dlo` and the name of the sales representative.

What I am trying to do is, to adjust the result to show clients without invoices for a particular sales representative i.e. the user.

I have a working script, that populates Dropdown select

```
    <form>
         <select name='repselect' onchange='showUser(this.value)'>
             <option value="here comes the value for id of sales representative 1">Sales Representative name 1</option>
             <option value="here comes the value for id of sales representative 2">Sales Representative name 2</option>
         </select>
    </form>
```

The ID in the Value field is bot `rowid` from table users and `fk_ser` from table societe_commerciaux.

I also have a working ajax script to populate the results.

The script is working as if I put `print $sql;` in it, I can see the query after I select a user.

What I am struggling with is how to adjust the above query to show only the results for the sales representative selected from the drop-down. I am passing this id to a file 'script.php' in which I have `$userid = intval($_GET['q']);` followed by the query. I can handle the output. It's just the query I am not able to adjust properly.

Comment: If `GROUP BY f.fk_soc
     , s.nom
     , f.datef
     , sc.fk_soc
     , sc.fk_user
     , u.rowid
     , u.firstname
     , u.lastname` does something different from `GROUP 
    BY s.rowid` then this is going to go badly.

Comment: As suggested, AND did the job. Working now. Added it after `JOIN societe_commerciaux sc ON s.rowid = sc.fk_soc`

Comment: Eh? Well, if it works, who am I to argue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query return users representative information from the clients who last invoice (facture) date is less than (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL) or never had an invoice:

```
$sql = '

SELECT 
  u.rowid,
  u.firstname,
  u.lastname
     
FROM societe s
INNER JOIN societe_commerciaux sc ON s.rowid = sc.fk_soc
INNER JOIN user u ON sc.fk_user = u.rowid

WHERE s.rowid NOT IN (
           SELECT f.fk_soc
           FROM facture f
           GROUP BY f.fk_soc
           HAVING MAX(f.datef) > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL ' . $db->escape($dlo) . ' DAY)

GROUP BY u.rowid, u.firstname, u.lastname
';
```

You should use prepared statement and no paste the parameter $dlo in a plain query, to prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final query I am using:

```
SELECT ';
    s.rowid, 
    s.nom, 
    s.phone, 
    s.email, 
    sc.fk_soc, 
    sc.fk_user, 
    u.rowid, 
    u.firstname, 
    u.lastname, 
    f.max_datef
FROM 
    ' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'societe s
INNER JOIN 
    ' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'societe_commerciaux sc ON s.rowid = sc.fk_soc
    AND sc.fk_user="' . $this->userId . '"
INNER JOIN 
    ' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'user u ON sc.fk_user = u.rowid
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Max($this->typeDate) As max_datef, fk_soc
    FROM
    ' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'facture
    GROUP BY fk_soc
    'HAVING max_datef <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL $this->interval DAY
) f ON s.rowid = f.fk_soc
ORDER BY max_datef ASC
```